# Trigger menu open when cursor on rightmost screen?

Tags: css, triggers, element, jscript

I'd like a right sided menu to open when cursor is moved over OR passed over the right most area of screen (body)

I could parse the cursor position and trigger after X pixels but would there be a CSS way to do this like placing a hidden element on right side?

it's nasty yes but has a specific purpose...

Answer (score 2):

You can go with something like this:

```
.menu {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: -199px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
}

.menu:hover {
  right: 0;
}
```

The only thing left here is to add animations (if needed) and style it so the line won't be visible.

Comment: Not good enough since mouse goes over that 1px and onto scrollbar and if you move it quickly it easily misses the 1px.

Comment: Go bigger then, 10px or so.